# Metaobject compiler for C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, metaobject

I need write a metaobject compiler for C (like a MOC in Qt). I will add to *.c source own keywords and mechanisms (like slots/signals in Qt).

I'll represent this work in three stages:

1. Writing C-code with own constructions
2. Parsing and generation of new source file without own constructions using metaobject compiler.
3. Compilation of file from stage 2 using, for example, GCC.

So, I have questions about second stage. MOC will be a pure C lexical analyzer/syntax analyzer with addition of analysing my constructions, right? Whether there are such pure C analyzers in the free access? Whether really to build in them parsing of my code? And generally, I think in the correct direction?

Comment: (1) Why can't you just use the Qt one directly? what do you need in particular (2) if you want to parse C / C++ AST's, I would recommend to use libclang to start I guess, and then modify it to support your MOC syntax.

Comment: Check out "C Front End" for a list of possible bases for your "MOC" parser.